# Set up a domain on a new server, but the I get a "server DNS address could not be found." Error

Tags: domains, dns, dns-servers

I am a noob when it comes to Servers and Web hosting so this may be the main issue. I bought a domian name on godaddy.com [here](http://livinghealth.tv). I am using a server with limestone networks to host the DNS server. I added the Domain with all the credentials (I think). I have the two NS, the A, and two CNAME's www and ftp. I am still getting a "server DNS address could not be found."

here is a pic of my Domain settings
[image]
It has been over 48 hours since I added the domain and NS. I ran a DNSreport and I got three main errors.

> No nameservers respond to queries via TCP. If no nameservers respond to TCP connections, this means that standard zone transfers (usually for slave DNS server replication) and most DNSSEC functions will not work. This can cause difficult to diagnose issues with those protocols. The nameservers that failed TCP queries are:
>
> Nameserver SOAs do not agree on the serial number. This is bad because
>   your nameservers may contain different resource record data and cause
>   delays or misrouting of packets. It is possible that you have just
>   made a change recently, and your secondary DNS servers haven't yet
>   received the new information from the master. The nameserver SOAs and
>   their mismatched serial numbers are:
>
> We were unable to connect to any of your WWW addresses listed. Users
>   will be unable to access your site until this is resolved.

Could these be the issues? I have a CNAME for the www. so I don't know why its unable to connect. Where can I look to figure out what to do? I turned my firewall off and I got the same problem so that is not the issue.

Comment: Can you add screen shots of your DNS settings? Otherwise we are just guessing.

Comment: @closetnoc yes sorry

Comment: Create an A record on the root domain which points to your server, then set your CNAME for www., alternatively you could create an A record for WWW. instead of a CNAME. Your domain is using the nameservers, but your nameservers are not responding with your records.

Comment: @Analog sorry this is the noob coming through, what is different about an A record on the root domain than what I have done?

Comment: @codegeek511 remove the "@." so your main A record is just "livinghealth.tv" are you using a control panel to edit these records or are you editing the actual record file? The CNAME record points a name to another name, instead of an IP while an A record point to an IP address. For example you www. CNAME is getting it's answer from your root domain A record.

Comment: If you are editing the actual record file in a text editor the proper syntax is "example.com. A 1.1.1.1", if you are using a control the extra "." after the domain will most likely not be needed.

Comment: @Analog Ok, so I now have two A records, one "livinghealth.tv" and the other "www.livinghealth.tv" both with the sam IP. I am using a control pannel, I am assuming its updating on my server

Comment: @codegeek511 Looks like the dns is propagating, im able to ping your root domain and www. and see your IP address. However your IP address is not responding to pings, are you sure this is the correct address?

Comment: @Analog also when I turn off the firewall I get a "www.livinghealth.tv refused to connect." error. So slightly different but still cannot connect.

Comment: Also you could re setup your CNAME for www. if you want instead if using 2 A records. The extra "@." was the issue. The failed to connect seems to be your webserver (or which ever server this IP is from you have set your A record to). Like i said your "*.*.227.94" is being resolved now but this IP is not responding. This is no longer a DNS issue since the IP you are pointing your domain to is not responding. The A record should be your web servers IP address.

Comment: @Analog Ok so....I will make a CNAME for the www. but then what?

Comment: also separate note, FTP and SSH work fine

Comment: @codegeek511 Is your webserver running on your server? I see that port 22 and 21 are open (ftp/ssh) but 80 (http) is not open. Do you have some sort of firewall that might be blocking the http port, or possibly your webserver (such as apache) is not running?

Comment: Also if ftp/ssh are working using your domain then this is no longer a DNS issue since your DNS is responding to queries with your IP address. :)

Comment: I bet you that the firewall is blocking port 80, also though even with the firewall off it won't connect. I have no idea if it's running or not. They just gave me the server and all I done on it is edit iptables and set up ftp

Comment: and yes the ftp works with the domain name so that issue is solved thank you!

Comment: and I am pretty sure I need to install apache hahahaha, thanks for putting up with my noobiness

Comment: @codegeek511 Oh well if this is a fresh server then possibly there is no webserver installed or it is not started. To me this sounds odd but try running "service httpd start" or "yum install httpd" if it is not installed (assuming you are running a RHEL OS such as Centos). Glad to help :p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just a formatting error.

Remove the "@." from your A record and it should work. You will have to wait for the changes to propagate (or flush your DNS cache).

Comment: As a warning that may not apply here so please just take for future info... many times people who are setting up DNS records that are not sure of the process are often setting them up on the host when the registrar is the authority. I always recommend using the registrar. Fewer steps and a lot less confusion. Much easier to make work. You can I can get it done, no question. But for those who are not DNS familiar, then even if we walk them through the process, there will be major confusion the next time around. Cheers!!